# Nothing contains everything

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> "It follows that, whatever the set $A$ may be, if $B =  \{x \in A: x \notin x \}, 
> $ then, for all $y$,

(*)   $ y\in B $ if and only if $(y \in A$ and $y \notin y)$

> Can it be that $B \in A$? We proceed to prove that the answer is no. Indeed, if $B \in A$, then either $B\in B$ also (unlikely, but not obviously impossible), or else $ B\notin B$. If $B\in B$, then, by ( * ), the assumption $B\in A$ yields $B \notin B$ -- a contradiction. If $B \notin B$, then, by ( * ) again, the assumption $B \in A$ yields $B \in B$--a contradiction again."

So this is from Halmos book (Naive Set Theory) under the axiom of specification section. Lets go step by step. If we are to assume that $B \in A$ there are logically only two possible scenarios then either $B\in B$ or else $ B\notin B$ (it is or it isn't). What I don't get is where do these contradictions come from? Why does $B \in A$ yield $B \in B$ if $B \notin B$ (going by ( * )) and vice versa. I can't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that $B\in A$ we have two possibilities.

**First possibility:** $B\in B$

In the case that $B\in B$, by assumption for this possibility, this contradicts what it means to be an element of $B$.  We had assumed also that $B\in A$, which our *definition* of $B$ is that all elements in $B$ are elements of $A$ which are not elements of themselves, i.e. $B\notin B$.

Since it is never true that something both is *and* isn't an element of something simultaneously, we see that this is an impossible scenario.

**Second possibility:** $B\notin B$

In the case that $B\notin B$, then this suggests that since we assumed $B\in A$ and $B\not\in B$, by definition of $B$ it is an element of $A$ which is not an element of itself, and therefore *should have been an element of $B$*.  Therefore, $B\in B$.  But, we had assumed that $B\not\in B$.  Again, since it is impossible for something to simultaneously be and not be an element of something else, this again reaches a contradiction.

---

Since either possibility yields a contradiction, neither possibility could be true.  This implies that there was a mistake in our assumptions somewhere, which implies that our mistake was either in assuming that $B\in A$, or perhaps even further back in assuming that the set $B=\{x\in A~:~x\not\in x\}$ is actually a set.

---

note the following two facts:

($x\in C$ or $x\notin C$) is always true

($x\in C$ and $x\notin C$) is always false

Comment: Pardon me if this question is dumb but where is our mistake then, the first or the latter?

Comment: So long as $B$ is not an element of $A$, then there is no problem.  Technically speaking, you will find that in ZFC, sets are never allowed to be elements of themselves.  As such, this definition of $B=\{a\in A~:~a\not\in a\}$ makes it such that $B=A$ since $a\not\in a$ is a redundant statement.

Comment: Done a quick google search of "ZFC" and found out what it means. How do I know which axiomatic system my book uses? Is there an official axiomatic system that is internationally accepted?

Comment: @Damjan if it doesn't specify, then it is almost certainly ZFC.  It is possibly just ZF (where the axiom of choice is not assumed) or Peano Arithmetic, but books teaching these specifically are becoming rarer in my experience.  Many elementary results are proven the same way in each system however, and the nuances of the differences boil down to the almost philosophical question of "*what a set actually is*."  It might be worth asking a separate question to find out when and in what contexts other axiomatic set theories are used.  Someone more familiar than I could hopefully provide insight.

Comment: @JMoravitz The OP mentions that they are using Halmos' book **Naive set theory**; as the title suggests, there is no formal theory in the background.

Comment: @NoahSchweber from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Set_Theory_%28book%29) "*While the title states that it is naive, which is usually taken to mean without axioms, the book does introduce all the axioms of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory and gives correct and rigorous definitions for basic objects.*"

Comment: @JMoravitz That's true, but my recollection is that the early parts of Halmos work without a fixed background theory.

Comment: @Noah Schweber very good point. Halmos book *needs* the internet to explain what he is talking about in _detail_ .

Answer (score 5):

Remember the definition of $B$: $$x\in B\iff x\in A\mbox{ and } x\not\in x.$$ So by definition, $$B\in B\iff B\in A\mbox{ and } B\not\in B.$$ So if $B\in A$, then this means $$B\in B\iff B\not\in B.$$ Do you see why this is true?

Comment: Yes, I do. It never came to me to place $B$ in place of $y$. Thank you.